# Kafka - partitioning messages on id given in runtime

Tags: apache-kafka

I got a producer: `P1`

It creates events like this:

```
Event: 
- id: uuid
- aggregateId: uuid
- payload: json
```

I got also consumers: `C1`, `C2`, `C3`

There is possibility that kubernetes will create more
consumers or kill them if they will be not necessary.

### Goal:

- I want to have all events with same `aggregateId`
  passed to same consumer.

`aggregateId` is dynamic - for example
it is just `userid` or `moneyTransferId` etc.
So it can't be defined upfront.

- if any consumer is down  all events with same `aggregateId`
  should be passed from now to another consumer
- if new consumer will occur new  events with unassigned `aggregateId`
  should be passed to any from consumers set (including new one) according to  load

### Question

Is this possible to setup in Apache Kafka?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can override Kafka `partitioner.class` in your producer to use record content rather than the default behavior of caching the key.

Or you can just set `aggregateId` as the key of the record, and that's what'll be partitioned on.

Consumers can still only be assigned one partition within a consumer group, and you cannot have more consumers than partitions.